# Is there a way to know how many times a static file is served or it has been served or not at all in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using express to serve static files.

```
app.use('/downloads', express.static('downloads'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that runs behind the scenes to serve static files in Express is quite simple ([in fact, it's a single file!](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static/blob/master/index.js)) - it doesn't deal with anything like logging or analytics.

If you want to add stuff like that, you will have to add a middleware to the chain that provides that functionality, either by using a third-party library or by writing your own.